# Can someone explain the different indices in this Google Colab Code?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm learning with the [Machine Learning Crash Course](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/mlcc/logistic_regression.ipynb?utm_source=mlcc&utm_campaign=colab-external&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=logisticregression-colab&hl=de#scrollTo=xaU7ttj8IYIF) from Google right now and I have a question regarding the Code.

Basically they change the Prediction output to a numpy array in several cases, but they change up the indices each time. I'm a little bit confused.

Example 1:

in train_linear_regressor_model:

```
training_predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in training_predictions])

validation_predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in validation_predictions])
```

Example 2:

in train_linear_classifier_model:

```
training_probabilities = np.array([item['probabilities'] for item in training_probabilities])

validation_probabilities = np.array([item['probabilities'] for item in validation_probabilities])
```

Example 3:

In building the ROC Curve:

```
validation_probabilities = np.array([item['probabilities'][1] for item in validation_probabilities])
```

So there are 3 cases in which the Predictions from the models get turned into a numpy array, but each time the index in which it gets appended is different.
Why?

I tried to see if there is a difference, when I change the index at Example 3, since the ROC Curve is dependent on it and that way I can directly see what changes if I change up the index from [1] to [0] or don't give an index at all.

Comment: Tell us about variables like `training_predictions`.  What's the type?  If `ndarray`, what's the `shape` and `dtype`.  Indexing with a string `item['probabilities']` means either `item` is a dictionary or a structured array (with indexing by field names).

Comment: I tried type() and print() the training_predictions: this is what I got:                
<class 'generator'>
<generator object Estimator.predict at 0x7f6c1dc03db0>

Comment: Then you need to tell us about `item`, an object produced by that generator.

Comment: I tried using print(tuple(str(item) for item in training_predictions)) and got this ("{'predictions': array([0.18258883], dtype=float32)}", "{'predictions': array([0.11683546], dtype=float32)}"...and many more) also this error after the 1st period: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [0, 12000]

Comment: So this looks like a dictionary (which accepts string key indexing), with array values (which take numerical indexing).